# Loading a BMP image at a specific index in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, glut

I have to load a 24 bit BMP file at a certain (x,y) index of glut window from a file using OpenGL. I have found a function that uses **glaux** library to do so. Here the color mentioned in `ignoreColor` is ignored during rendering.

```
void iShowBMP(int x, int y, char filename[], int ignoreColor)
{
    AUX_RGBImageRec *TextureImage;
    TextureImage = auxDIBImageLoad(filename);
    int i,j,k;
    int width = TextureImage->sizeX;
    int height = TextureImage->sizeY;
    int nPixels = width * height;
    int *rgPixels = new int[nPixels];

    for (i = 0, j=0; i < nPixels; i++, j += 3)
    {
        int rgb = 0;
        for(int k = 2; k >= 0; k--)
        {
            rgb = ((rgb << 8) | TextureImage->data[j+k]);
        }

        rgPixels[i] = (rgb == ignoreColor) ? 0 : 255;
        rgPixels[i] = ((rgPixels[i] << 24) | rgb);
    }

    glRasterPos2f(x, y);
    glDrawPixels(width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, rgPixels);

    delete []rgPixels;
    free(TextureImage->data);
    free(TextureImage);
}
```

But the problem is that glaux is now obsolete. If I call this function, the image is rendered and shown for a minute, then an error pops up (without any error message) and the glut window disappears. From the returned value shown in the console, it seems like a runtime error.

Is there any alternative to this function that doesn't use glaux? I have seen **cimg**, **devil** etc but none of them seems to work like this `iShowBMP` function. I am doing my project in Codeblocks.

I have to load every frame to keep the implementation consistent with other parts of the program. Also, the bmp file whose name has been passed as a parameter to the function has both width and height in powers of 2.

Comment: Are you loading the image every frame? You might consider loading it once, returning the `rgPixels` pointer, and then just calling the two gl functions using that persistently loaded data. Even though you don't appear to be leaking memory you could still have issues with fragmentation and loading every frame is terribly inefficient.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I have to load every frame to keep the implementation consistent with other parts of the program.

Comment: Loading every frame is not at all scalable. If you've made design choices that make this necessary it's time to take a serious look at fixing that design.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I didn't make any design choice. A wrapper of OpenGL was developed a long ago, and I am just fixing the new issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last two free() statements were not getting executed for some unknown reasons, so the memory consumption was increasing. That's why the program was crashing after a moment. Later I solved it using stb_image.h.